# how to create a subscriber node that also publishes message?

Tags: ros, node, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I'm wondering if it's possible to create a node that serves both as a subscriber and a publisher at the same time? It will receive some messages and publish some messages to other topic.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h>

void mapConvert(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard:1");
  pub.publish(msg->info.width);//or just simply pub.publish(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "map_converter");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("map", 1000, mapConvert);
  ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<int>("mapconverted", 1000);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

 int count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
     ros::spinOnce();
     loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried this structure but it did not work.Please Help! Thank You in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227499/how-to-create-a-subscriber-node-that-also-publishes-message?/) by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you need to implement a [service](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(c%2B%2B)).

But if you really need to use publisher, you should make publisher accessable from function by making global pointer.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h>
    
ros::Publisher * pub;

void mapConvert(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg)
{
      ROS_INFO("I heard:1");
      pub->publish(msg->info.width);//or just simply pub.publish(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "map_converter");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("map", 1000, mapConvert);
  pub = new ros::Publisher(n.advertise<int>("mapconverted", 1000));
  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

 int count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
     ros::spinOnce();
     loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  ros::spin();
  delete pub;
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) with karma: 223 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0